# scala case class default argument

Tags: scala

I faced the following definition in some source code:

```
case class Task(uuid: String = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString, n: Int)
```

Here the first argument declared with default value, but I don't understand how to create instance with this default value. 
If I can not pass the first argument like `Task(1)` then I certainly get compilation error.

However the following change works fine:

```
case class Task(n: Int, uuid: String = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString)
```

But here, as showed in the definition, `uuid` is a first argument.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Scala functions, whenever you omit a parameter (for a default value), all the following parameters (if provided) are required to be provided with names.

So, if you gave a function like following,

```
def abc(i1: Int, i2: Int = 10, i3: Int = 20) = i1 + i2 + i3
```

You can use it in following ways,

```
abc(1)

abc(1, 2)

abc(1, 2, 3)
```

But if you want to use default value of i2 and provide a value for i3 then,

```
abc(1, i3 = 10)
```

So, in your case, you can use it like following,

```
val task = Task(n = 100)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have `Task` class defined like this `case class Task(uuid: String = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString, n: Int)`, you may create new instance only with `n` argument in such way:

```
Task(n = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The important point here is: If you have a class/method definition that take `n` parameters but you need pass to only 1 to `n-1` arguments; you use the name of the arguments with `=` sign and then the value of the argument you want to pass on, so in your case:

`val task = Task(n=2)`